# Unix: Command to display only filename without path created within last 1 day

Tags: shell, unix, find

I want to display only the filenames created within last 1 day without path. I am trying below command but in prints path also. please advise.

**Command:**

```
find /path -mtime -1 -exec ls {} \;
```

**Ouput:**

```
/path/1.txt
/path/2.txt
```

**Expected Output:**

```
1.txt
2.txt
```

Comment: tell find the how to format the info it is printing with the `-printf` option: `find /path -mtime -1 -printf "%f\n"` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find /path -mtime -1 -exec basename {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works !! Will accept this answer within 10 minutes when it allows me to do so :)

Answer (score 1):

There is an option for that in GNU find:

```
find /path -mtime -1 -printf "%f\n"
```

See e.g. here for an explanation of the possible format strings: http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/find1.html

Comment: You're welcome, checkout these args for find as well, 
-maxdepth 1 - search immediate directory.
-type f  - searches files only

Answer (score 1):

This one too works fine,

```
 find /path -mtime -1 -printf "%f" ;
```

-printf  with %f option File's name with any leading directories removed only  the last element is printed.